# How to realize tsql "IN" equivalent using dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic

I'm creating a generic form (C#) which can receive any Linq query. In this form I want to be able to add filters (WHERE clauses). For operators like '=', '>', 'Like', etc. I can do things like `IQueryable.Where(someFieldname + "> @0", someCriteria)`. But when I want to be able to do the equivalent of a T-sql "IN" I am totally lost. I've searched hours, but cannot find a way to realize it.

When thinking about it a way that it should be possible is to put the values for the IN-clause in a string array or some other simple list of strings. Then join this list with the base query. But how can I join these two when base query can be any query?

Example: 
Say my base query is something like:

```
IQueryable<Object> q = from a in db.Adresses
                       select new { a.Street, a.HouseNr };
```

In the form I want to be able to filter on HouseNr like this: Where HouseNr IN (1, 3, 5)
The numbers (1, 3, 5) are available in a string array (or any other List of strings).

How can I achieve this, knowing that the base query can be anything?

Comment: I don't think a single person understood your question. You can use Dynamic Linq to generate a list of `OR` statements, though this isn't *exactly* the same as the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] list = new[]{1, 3, 5};
IQueryable<Object> q = from a in db.Adresses
                       where list.Contains(a.HouseNr)
                       select new { a.Street, a.HouseNr };
```

Comment: This works indeed when you have a object named Adresses, but what I have is a query that can be anything. I need a dynamic solution, not a solution in which I hardcoded refer to Linq objects.

Comment: @Stefan you can still use Contains() on  dynamic query results in the same way.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? I just can't seem to figure it out correctly.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? Thx for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`Contains` maps to `IN` when the SQL is generated.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };

var q = from a in db.Addresses
        where numbers.Contains(a.HouseNr)
        select new { a.Street, a.HouseNr }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isnt a solution to my problem. I used Addresses as an example. Replace Adresses by any IQueryable object: what would your solution be?

Answer (score 0):

How about like this...

```
string[] Numbers = new string[]{"1", "3", "5"};
IQueryable<Object> q = db.Adresses.Where(a => Numbers.Contains(h.HouseNr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...doesn't the `.Intersect()` method return the values of a list where values exist in both?